# How to add standard reports to Lighting component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, reporting, iframe

I tried iframes, Lightning Container, but no luck.
ReportChart is not an option.
Is there a way to include standard reports inside lighting component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible currently to embed a standard report into a custom lightning component. Only way I could think of is building a custom component using the [Salesforce Reports and Dashboards REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_intro.htm) which gives you programmatic access to your report and dashboard data as defined in the report builder and dashboard builder. The API lets you integrate the data into any web or mobile application, inside or outside the Salesforce platform. For example, you might use the API to trigger a Chatter post with a snapshot of top-performing reps each quarter.

Comment: Thank you for letting know the possibilities. 
Could you help me understand the advantages we get if Reports Rest API instead of developing everything in custom.

Comment: @Alex The advantage is you can build dynamic components to accept your standard report as inputs and hook up the api to get the data of the standard reports. Or build a component to get data from apex class where you write your own logic to build custom data